# Toolbar in CoordinatorLayout is invisible in Android 4.4( visible in Android 5.0 )

Tags: android, android-layout

It's a layout with a toolbar,a webView and a floating actionButton(there should be a floating action button in android 5.0):

[image]

I'm using CoordinatorLayout because there's a floating action button in it. If change it to LinearLayout, action bar will be visible but the FloatingActionButton won't float on the screen. Changing CoordinatorLayout to FrameLayout doesn't make any change. How to deal with this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_custom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_favorite"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_favorite_white_24dp"
        app:layout_behavior="com.drunkpiano.zhihuselection.utilities.ScrollingFavoriteFABBehavior" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Manifest：

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.drunkpiano.zhihuselection">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.WebViewActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.FavoritesActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.GuideActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.AnyActivity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <!--<item name="android:listDivider">@drawable/shape_divider</item>-->
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />


    <style name="ListItemText" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.TextView">
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:layout_margin">5dip</item>
        <item name="android:minLines">3</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ThemeOverlay.YourApp" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
    <style name="ActionBarTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" >
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: What is mean by `Toolbar` invisible in `4.4` ?

Comment: i think toolbar is visible. Red bar tool bar i thinkl

Comment: @sush it is visible in android studio but not on nexus 5 kitkat..

Comment: please post your android manifest.

Comment: problem solved, I added "            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
" to the WebView.